# Linux VM console on Azure

Tags: linux, azure, console, azure-virtual-machine

I have created a new linux Virtual Machine on MS Azure cloud. I am not able to access the console of the new machine. I have enabled "boot diagnostics" for the VM but want to access console during boot time for troubleshooting in case of any issues.

Comment: Only SSH access atm, you can open a support ticket, you have access in the past with SSH?

Comment: Ensure your kernel is booting with the parameters `console=ttyS0 earlyprintk=ttyS0`

Answer (score 0):

The "Boot diagnostics" feature will show you the console output or a screenshot during the VM boot process, to help you understand what's going wrong, but does not give you access to the VM itself.

To access your Linux VM you should connect via SSH, as usual.

Comment: What about if you don't have the SSH credentials? Is there a way to view them?

Comment: you can reset VM credentials through portal.azure.com